# Creating an Instance only if the Condition Satisfies

Tags: arrays, object, swift4, instance

I am creating a program in Swift 4 which has two Classes StockHolding(Parent) and ForeignStockHolding(Child). I need to create some objects of these classes and add them to an array which I did manually like this:

```
var stocksInArray: [StockHolding] = [] //creating array of type StockHolding
var newSIA = StockHolding()

//=========New StockHolding Object===========
    **newSIA = StockHolding()**
    newSIA.purchaseSharePrice = 2
    newSIA.currentSharePrice = 3
    newSIA.numberOfShares = 5
    newSIA.companyName = "A"

    //Appending the Array
    stocksInArray.append(newSIA)

//=========New ForeignStockHolding Object===========
    **newSIA = ForeignStockHolding()**
    newSIA.purchaseSharePrice = 6.10
    newSIA.currentSharePrice = 99.51
    newSIA.numberOfShares = 310
    newSIA.companyName = "D"

    //Appending the Array
    stocksInArray.append(newSIA)
```

The next part is to ask the user how many stocks he wants and of which type (StockHolding or ForeignStockHolding) and according to the choice I need to create the object and append that to an array. I was trying to do the following but it is not working as the objects are not yet created because they are within the condition and I am getting errors.

```
for stocks in 1...maxVal {
        print("Type of stock \(stocks): 1.Local  2.Foreign " )

        input = readLine()!
        let s1 = Int(input)!

        if(s1 == 1){  var newSIA = StockHolding()
            runOnCondition()
        }
        else if (s1 == 2){ var newSIA = ForeignStockHolding()
            print("Enter Conversion Rate")
            input = readLine()!
            let cr = Float(input)!
            newSIA.conversionRate = cr
            runOnCondition()
        }
    }
```

I don't even know if I am doing it all wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work if you declare the variable outside the conditions using the parent class, like this:

```
for stocks in 1...maxVal {
    print("Type of stock \(stocks): 1.Local  2.Foreign " )

    input = readLine()!
    let s1 = Int(input)!
    var newSIA: StockHolding

    if(s1 == 1){  newSIA = StockHolding()
        runOnCondition()
    }
    else if (s1 == 2){ newSIA = ForeignStockHolding()
        print("Enter Conversion Rate")
        input = readLine()!
        let cr = Float(input)!
        newObj.conversionRate = cr
        runOnCondition()
    }
}
```

Comment: The Problem is still the same. When we make the Object outside the statement, it is of type StockHolding(). In the else part we need ForeignStockHolding() and this else part will only run after the program compiles. So any of the code inside else part which needs the ForeignStockHolding() Objects shows the error.

I was looking for this solution only because I did not want to duplicate the same code in if and else part. Otherwise, the program is running fine.